# Copy a Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, iis

I just need to pass from test.mysite.com to prod.mysite.com leaving both availables.

I copied the project and I renamed it. I created the site on IIS and set the path to /public but it gets me an 404 error.

I've never worked with laravel, so I don't know if I have to run an extra config.

Please, somebody help me!

Comment: Did you create web.config file in IIS for this Laravel project? Example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jatubio/80dfc57fc18546706ec0). And you can also read this [discussion on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/iis7-laravel-5)

Comment: Yes, I did. the test.mysite.com is working with the web.config and I copied all but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, I just needed to set Public and Storage full permissions and run `composer update`